# PHP can't open file in thread running context

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

i' m working on a monitor for a structure composed by a lot of computers. I develop it in PHP and i want to ping all the structure by the quickest way.
For this i use the multi-thread inherited from pthread [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pthreads.php) So i follow some tutorials and finally i have one class (extended from Thread) and a caller in an other script :

The class :

```
class Ping extends Thread{
        public $id;
        public $name;
    public function __construct($id, $name){
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function run(){
        $ping = exec("ping -n 1 -w 80 " . $this->name);
        $h = fopen("ping.json", 'w');
        if(preg_match("#perte 100#", $ping)){               
            fwrite($h,'d');
        }
        else {
            fwrite($h,'c');         
        }
        fclose($h);
    }
}
```

The caller :

```
$p = array();
foreach($array_computer as $comp){          
        array_push($p, new Ping(array_search ($comp , $array_computer),  $comp->{'name'}));
    }       
    foreach ($p as $p_t){
        $p_t->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_ALL);
    }
```

So i have two problems :

1 . When i want to echo $id or $name, nothing is display

2 . I can't open 'ping.json' because :  "failed to open stream: Permission denied"

If i replace

```
$p_t->start(PTHREADS_INHERIT_ALL);
```

by

```
$p_t->run();
```

The call works but i lose the interest of multithread :P

Answer (score 0):

Could it be var `$p_t` that is an instance of Ping?

```
foreach ($p as $p_t)
```

Also try checking for instance ie.

```
if ($p_t instanceof Ping) {
  $p_t->start();
}
```

Comment: It's not the problem, i already tried it. I tried to put the file handle in parameter of the Ping class but i have the same problem, except when i try with just one Ping object.

Comment: I would second @C. van Dorsten comments above. Validations and debugging where appropriate, top-down. There are some examples at [http://php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php]

Answer (score 0):

Some question/remarks to help you along:

1. you are writing something to a file based on a computername, but has
   this name a value? Otherwise the output file will be empty and you
   won't get a result.
2. Within the foreach, echo the parameters you want to store in $p so
   you know you are putting something in there.
3. where does the start method come from? Is $p an array of objects
   object? Is so, where is the method declared?
4. $comp->{'name'} looks odd to me; why not use $comp->name if it's an
   object or $comp['name'] if it's an array?
5. you are not storing any resulting values in your public variables; therefore
   when an input value is blank, it wil stay blank.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers,
i found an other solution by storing data results in a database into the run() function. 
I think that some conflicts appeared when i want to write the json file at the same time, and lock the file with [flock()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.flock.php) wasn't efficient.

I put the Ping class and the caller in the same file and ordinate the thread excution like this :

```
$i = 0;
    foreach ($p as $p_t){
        while($i > 15){}            
        $i++;
        $p_t->start();
        if($p_t->join())$i--;
    }
```